# Storing the distance between two shapefiles as an attribute in QGIS 3.0?

Tags: qgis, distance, qgis-3

I have this map of Mexico that is broken down into all of the municipalities. How would I create a variable that has the distance between each municipality and Mexico City?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends... firstly on whether you want (A) distance between the centroid of each municipality and Mexico city, or (B) shortest distance between each municipality and Mexico city; and also whether your map is (a) projected or (b) not-projected (latlong) data.

Please find below four sample expressions for the Field Calculator.
In this example I have a `Mexico_city` point layer which has only one point (i.e. Mexico city) so it's `id` is zero(0). Open the attribute table of your municipality layer and start the Field Calculator.

(A)(a) Municipality centroid - Mexico city on a projected map

```
distance(centroid($geometry), geometry(get_feature_by_id('Mexico_city', 0)))/1000
```

(A)(b) Municipality centroid - Mexico city on a non-projected map (e.g. GADM data - [Mexico](http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/diva/adm/MEX_adm.zip))

```
distance( transform(centroid($geometry), 
                    'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:32614'), 
          transform(geometry(get_feature_by_id('Mexico_city', 0)), 
                    'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:32614'))/1000
```

(B)(a) Shortest distance, Municipality - Mexico city on a projected map

```
distance(closest_point($geometry, geometry(get_feature_by_id('Mexico_city', 0))), 
         geometry(get_feature_by_id('Mexico_city', 0)))/1000
```

(B)(b) Shortest distance, Municipality - Mexico city on a non-projected map (e.g. GADM data - [Mexico](http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/diva/adm/MEX_adm.zip))

```
distance(transform(closest_point($geometry, 
                   geometry(get_feature_by_id('Mexico_city', 0))), 
                   'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:32614'), 
         transform(geometry(get_feature_by_id('Mexico_city', 0)), 
                   'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:32614'))/1000
```

Comment: [@Kazuhito](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/84455/kazuhito), definitely a nice answer, however, I think you forgot to add the explanation of how to create a field which stores the new data. [@TDonnally](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/123066/tdonnally), please open your layer in edited mode then add a press a `"New field"` and make it `Decimal number` with 10 digits length, and 2 digits precision. I am sure it would be enough. A short tutorial on working with attribute table could found [here](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html).

Comment: I chose to use the centroid expression for projections and in the distance column all of the numbers are around the same value when there should be larger differences. I don't know what I did wrong.

Comment: Probably your layer is in an unprojected CRS, and its units are decimal degrees. So the `distance()` function calculate the distances in decimal degrees. If that's the case, you should use one of the calculations that transforms your layers before calculating distance. Be sure to substitute the actual CRS of your layer where the formula says `'EPSG:4326'`